# Searching file for user-inputed keyword, then printing each line with keyword in it

Tags: python

For my assignment, I was given a text file named 'measles.txt' which contains A LOT of information, but most importantly, I'm focused on the year for each line. My task is to make a program that reads 'measles.txt', prompts the user for the year, and outputs every line with that year into another text file.

The problem that I can't figure out is that my professor specified that it has to work if the user inputs an incomplete year. For example, a line whose Year field contains “1987” would be selected by any of the following user responses:  {“1”, “19”, “198”, “1987”}

Also, if the user inputs "","all", or "ALL", it has to output all the lines from the text file.

Here's measles.txt: https://bpaste.net/show/ade0a362b882

My current code is this:

```
input_file = open('measles.txt', 'r')
output_file_name = input("Please enter the name of the output file: ")
output_file = open(output_file_name, 'w')

for line in input_file:
    output_file.write(line)

output_file.close()
input_file.close()
```

Comment: Added the link in the post

Comment: It's actually amazing how much stuff one can learn on SO from doing other people's homework.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. You can check whether a year starts with a certain string (for example `'1'` or `'200'`), this code below should return all the matching lines.

EDIT:

It seems like you found this code too complex but you made a mistake while copy/pasting and broke your solution. I modified your code to simplify it even more and fix it.

```
input_file = open('measles.txt', 'r')
year = input("Please enter a year: ")
output_file_name = input("Please enter the name of the output file: ")
output_file = open(output_file_name, 'w')

for line in input_file:
    if year in ("", "all", "ALL") or line.split()[-1].startswith(year):
        output_file.write(line)

output_file.close()
input_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a much simpler answer. Since the year number in measles.txt is 88 characters from the beginning, I used that to create an if/elif statement.

```
input_file = open('measles.txt', 'r')
year = input("Please enter a year: ")
output_file_name = input("Please enter the name of the output file: ")
output_file = open(output_file_name, 'w')

#   For loop that checks the end of the file for the year number
for line in input_file:
    if year == line[88:88+len(year)]:
        output_file.write(line)
    elif year == ("", "all", "ALL"):
        output_file.write(line)

output_file.close()
input_file.close()
```